# Understanding param's of TensorFlow 2.x Attention layer

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I'm reading the documentation on [tf.keras.layers.Attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Attention) in TensorFlow website. The documentation says the call argument takes **Query Tensor, Value Tensor**.
My question is what are these tensor. Are they,

- Query Tensor = lstm output
- Value Tensor = lstm hidden state

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value Tensor --> This is the Encoder representation of every time step. 
Query Tensor --> This is decoder representation at the current time step if you are calculating time stepwise. If you are calculating attention for every time step, it is a tensor representing every time step of decoder output.

Comment: So, Value Tensor is "encoder output" and Query Tensor is "decoder output"